# Fabric used as library not working

Tags: python, fabric

I cannot get fabric working when used as a library within my own python scripts. I made a very short example `fabfile.py` to demonstrate my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import *

print("Hello")

def test():
    with settings(host_string='myIp', user="myUser", password="myPassword"):
        run("hostname")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   test()
```

Running `fab` works like a charm:

```
$ fab test
Hello
[myIp] run: hostname
[myIp] out: ThisHost
[myIp] out:


Done.
Disconnecting from myUser@myIp... done.
```

Ok, now, running the python script without fab seems to break somewhere:

```
$ python fabfile.py
Hello
[myIp] run: hostname
```

It immediatly returns, so it does not even seem to wait for a response. Maybe there are errors, but I don't see how to output those.

I am running this script inside my vagrant virtual machine. As `fab` executes without any errors, I guess this should not be a problem!

**UPDATE**

The script seems to crash as it does not execute anything after the first `run`. `local` on the other hand works!

We executed the script on a co-workers laptop and it runs without any issues. I am using Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04 with fabric 1.5.1, so I guess there is a problem with some of this! Is there any way to debug this properly?

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced a similar issue, that the fab command exited without error but just a blank line on the first `run()`/`sudo()` command.

So I put the `run()` command into a try: except: block and printed the traceback:

```
def do_something():
    print(green("Executing on %(host)s as %(user)s" % env))
    try:
        run("uname -a")
    except:
        import traceback
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        print(tb)
```

I saw that it the script exited in the `fabfile/network.py` at line 419 when it caught an EOFError or TypeError. I modified the script to:

```
...
except (EOFError, TypeError) as err:
    print err
    # Print a newline (in case user was sitting at prompt)
    print('')
    sys.exit(0)
...
```

which then printed out:

```
connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sock'
```

So I remove the sock keyword argument in the connect method a few lines above and it worked like charm. I guess it is a problem with a `paramiko` version, that does not allow the sock keyword.

Versions:

```
Python 2.7.3
Fabric >= 1.5.3
paramiko 1.10.0
```

Comment: Problem resolved. I think for some reason Fabric picked a different ssh library than `paramiko`.

Comment: Does this mean I have to uninstall paramiko? Or install something else beside fabric?

Comment: No, just make sure, you don't have any other ssh library in your python `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the fab command it looks like this:

```
sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('Fabric==1.4.3', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
)
```

this means it looks for a block labeled console_scripts in a file called entry_points.txt in the Fabric package and executes the methods listed there, in this case fabric.main:main

when we look at this method we see argument parsing, interesting fabfile importing and then:

```
if fabfile:
    docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
    state.commands.update(callables)
....
for name, args, kwargs, arg_hosts, arg_roles, arg_exclude_hosts in commands_to_run:
    execute(
            name,
            hosts=arg_hosts,
            roles=arg_roles,
            exclude_hosts=arg_exclude_hosts,
            *args, **kwargs
        )
```

with some experimentation we can come up with something like:

```
from fabric import state
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.tasks import execute
from fabric.network import disconnect_all

def test():
    with settings(host_string='host', user="user", password="password"):
        print run("hostname")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    state.commands.update({'test': test})
    execute("test") 

    if state.output.status:
        print("\nDone.")
    disconnect_all()
```

which is obviously very incomplete, but perhaps you only need to add the

```
disconnect_all()
```

line at the end of your script

Comment: Thanks for your work! I don't think that much work is needed. As said, my script runs just fine on the laptop of a co-worker (he uses Windows7 and Python 2.7).

Comment: There is also a section in the docs about how to use fabric as a library: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/library.html